# Raring Wubi Won't Work

Tags: wubi, 13.04

I was trying to install Raring to my system using Wubi, but I can't find the option to do so.

Is there a reason I cannot find the Windows Installer for Raring?

Answer (score 0):

Wubi was dropped from Ubuntu 13.04 raring. Read this [here](http://techkronos.com/2013/04/11/ubuntu-13-04-wubi-no-more/).

Answer (score 0):

WUBI is not supposed to work on 13.04. I know it still shows in the Daily images, but on the final official release it will be removed.

This is because WUBI has created many problems regarding the installation of Ubuntu, ranging from incompatibility between UEFI systems, to very rare errors that happen in Ubuntu because of a Wubi installed vs a LiveCD installed.

You can find the official warning on the Ubuntu site as mentioned by OMGUBUNTU: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/04/wubi-advice

**Official Site**: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer

You can also find the information regarding the drop of WUBI: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/04/wubi-unlikely-to-be-in-ubuntu-13-04-windows-users-lose-out

And although it shows as a negative thing for Windows users, it actually encourages users to use the correct method by which they have less problems related to Ubuntu. Of course this will leave out the option of partitioning the drive from within Windows to avoid any problems related to it, but then again, this problems were mostly in Windows 8 with UEFI enabled.

Comment: Luis, you may want to read Oli's response on [this meta post which you answered](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6504/should-we-stop-supporting-wubi-questions-for-13-04), you could've saved yourself the need to write this out.

Comment: @TheLordofTime good point.